# Does SmsRetriever work on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, google-play-services

I am attempting to implement Automatic SMS Verification with the SMS Retriever API, [as described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request).

To initially test this I had planned on using the Android Emulator and manually sending SMS messages using its GUI interface:

[image]

However, my BroadcastReceiver callback is never invoked:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

        switch(status.getStatusCode()) {
            case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // Get SMS message contents
                String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                Log.i(TAG, "Got message: " + message);
                // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                // by sending the code back to your server.
                break;
            case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                // Waiting for SMS timed out (5 minutes)
                // Handle the error ...
                break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Does the [`SmsRetriever`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/phone/SmsRetriever) class work inside the [Android emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html)?

Comment: Based from this [tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/googles-sms-retriever-api-6540eb3c8e9c), make sure that you have registered the `BroadcastReceiver` in your Manifest file. There is also a [forum](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/issues/21) wherein it stated that for testing purposes you should be able to send text messages "manually" via `adb` or the emulator, rather than setting up the service.

Answer (score 3):

I was not properly computing my App's Hash String:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string

This is a six-step process:

1. Get your app's public key certificate as a lower-case hex string.
   For example, to get the hex string from your keystore, type the
   following command:

   `keytool -alias MyAndroidKey -exportcert -keystore MyProduction.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]"`
2. Append the hex
   string to your app's package name, separated by a single space.
3. Compute the SHA-256 sum of the combined string. Be sure to remove
   any leading or trailing whitespace from the string before computing
   the SHA-256 sum.
4. Base64-encode the binary value of the SHA-256 sum.
   You might need to decode the SHA-256 sum from its output format
   first.
5. Your app's hash string is the first 11 characters of the
   base64-encoded hash.

Once computed, you have to send a specially-crafted SMS message to your device starting with a `<#>` and ending with this app hash string; just any old SMS message will not do.

Note that the command-line steps using `keytool` above to extract my App's hash string never did work for me; I had to use the [helper class Google provided](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java).

Comment: But the playstore release is not working with the helper class google provided. I don't know what to do!

Comment: How exactly do we perform this sub-step 4? `"You might need to decode the SHA-256 sum from its output format first."`

Comment: I am also unable to generate the key. Using google provided class it is working but when i signed the APK then it's not working. I need to generate different key but class doesn't provide that. Can you help guys?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue here is the incorrect hash string. Please note that **debug and release hash strings are usually different**.

To get this hash string you can follow the instructions in the accepted answer. But here's an **alternative approach** with a quick code snippet:

```
class AppSignatureHelper(context: Context?) :
    ContextWrapper(context) {// Get all package signatures for the current package

    // For each signature create a compatible hash
    /**
     * Get all the app signatures for the current package
     *
     * @return
     */
    val appSignatures: ArrayList<String>
        get() {
            val appCodes = ArrayList<String>()
            try {
                // Get all package signatures for the current package
                val packageName = packageName
                val packageManager = packageManager
                val signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                    packageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
                ).signatures

                // For each signature create a compatible hash
                for (signature in signatures) {
                    val hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString())
                    if (hash != null) {
                        appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash))
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e)
            }
            return appCodes
        }

    companion object {

        val TAG = AppSignatureHelper::class.java.simpleName

        private const val HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256"

        const val NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9

        const val NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11

        private fun hash(packageName: String, signature: String): String? {
            val appInfo = "$packageName $signature"
            try {
                val messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE)
                messageDigest.update(appInfo.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                var hashSignature = messageDigest.digest()

                // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
                hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES)
                // encode into Base64
                var base64Hash =
                    Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING or Base64.NO_WRAP)
                base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR)
                Log.v(
                    TAG + "sms_sample_test",
                    String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, base64Hash)
                )
                return base64Hash
            } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
                Log.v(TAG + "sms_sample_test", "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm", e)
            }
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call from, for example, your application class:

```
        val appSignature = AppSignatureHelper(this)
        val signature = appSignature.appSignatures[0]
```